# Parsing only updated data from NSDictionary into Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, nsdictionary

I receive data about a user in the form of an NSDictionary, and have been parsing it into Core Data entities.  The problem is that parsing all the keys in this dictionary can take a long time, and the data isn't always different from what I already have stored.  Since the data isn't updated most of the time, a lot of time is wasted creating fetch requests for each part of the dictionary only to see that it hasn't changed.

I tried saving the [NSDictionary description] as an attribute for the user entity, and comparing that string to the dictionary description received from the server. As expected, it was even slower than parsing the dictionary.  I've also thought about generating a checksum from the dictionary description.  Is there an obvious solution I'm not seeing here for updating data?

Comment: I like your idea about the checksum. That's pretty quick and it will also let you compare binary files using the same method.

Comment: How do receive the user info, and how much control do have over what gets sent?

Comment: I receive it every minute or so, and I don't have control over what is being sent.  Basically polling a server for user info, and checking to see what's changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `-(NSUInteger) hash` method instead of creating the checksum yourself? It is declared in the [NSObject Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash)

Comment: This was really promising, but it turns out the hash for an NSDictionary is always the number of entries in the dictionary.  Maybe get the hash key of the description string...

Comment: That seemed to be what I was looking for.  Storing the [[NSDictionary description] hash] and comparing to the new one did the trick!